# Array multiplication puzzle in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

I want to get:

```
output = [1,2,6,24,120]
```

Hope you see the pattern and what I want to accomplish here. `x[1]` is 
transformed into `x[1]*x[0]`. `x[2]` => `x[2]*x[1]*x[0]`, etc.

What's the most efficient way to do this in Ruby?

Comment: shouldn't the last number be 120 instead of 60?

Comment: So, for all `i>0`, `out[i] = x[i]*out[i-1]`?

Comment: sorry for my stupid mistake! Just fixed, thanks
@jimbojw: nope, I actually need this for a time series manipulation. A nd the only way I know how to do this is via stupid for loop, so I am trying to see if ruby has a smarter way to do it

Comment: this abstraction is called scanl in functional languages: http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/scanl_f.html. And you would write it: scanl1 (*) [1,2,3,4,5] #=> [1,2,6,24,120]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use e.g. the following code

```
a=1;output = x.map{|i|a*=i}
```

Comment: the `map` does apply to each element of `x` updating the variable `a` accordingly (i.e. all elements are multiplied one after the other). Since the assignment at the same time returns its result the map operation collects these intermediary results and thus yields the desired array.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [1,2,3]
arr.each_with_index.map do |x,i|  
  arr[0..i].inject(1) { |total,y| total *= y } }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it

```
prev = 1
puts [1,2,3,4,5].map { |n| prev *= n }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
1.9.2 (main):0 > a
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
1.9.2 (main):0 > a.inject([]) {|arr, e| arr << a[0..arr.size].inject(:*) }
```

It's a nice way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty general abstraction, usually called [scanl](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/scanl_f.html) in functional languages. A possible Ruby implementation:

```
module Enumerable
  def scanl(&block)
    self.inject([]) do |acc, x| 
      acc.concat([acc.empty? ? x : yield(acc.last, x)])
    end
  end
end

>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].scanl(&:*)
=> [1, 2, 6, 24, 120]
```

Comment: I wanted to write up a feature request for `Enumerable#scan` for *years* now, but I always get side-tracked ...

Comment: @JörgWMittag: we first should find a suitable name, as there is already a completely unrelated `String#scan`. maybe `Enumerable#partial_inject`?

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to make a recursive solution.

```
F(x) =  if x < 1 return 0
        else     return A(x) * F(x - 1)
```

In the simplest mathematical form, where F is your result array, and A is your source array (with indices as x).

Answer (score 0):

just for fun

```
[1,2,3,4,5].map.with_index{|a,i| ar[0,i+1].inject(:*)}
```

Answer (score 0):

`x.inject([]) do |result, arr_element|
  last_num = result.last
  result << (last_num.nil? ? arr_element : last_num * arr_element)
  result
end`

use inject and pass array as accumulator